# Populate 2nd Dropdown based on 1st Dropdown Choice

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is when someone clicks the first html dropdown `id="FirstDD"`, based on the `option` chosen the second dropdown `id="SecDD"` would populate with the fields that correlate to `FirstDD` dropdowns choice. Triggering this all is ajax to do the initial call and php to handle from there in `subcategories.php`.

Currently, what is happening is: i selected the first dropdown, but nothing gets populated in `SecDD`

**JS/AJAX:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FirstDD").change(function(){
        $('#SecDD').load('inc/subcategories.php?scatID='+this.value);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
   <select style="width:300px;" id="FirstDD" name="userListingCategory">
                    <!--onchange="$('#SecDD').load('inc/subcategories.php?scatID='+this.value);"-->
                          <option  disabled="disabled">Category...</option>
                          <?php while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                          {echo "<option value=". $categoryID . ">" .$row['catName']."</option>";}
                        unset($sth2);
                        ?>

                    </select> 
                   <select style="width:340px;" id="SecDD" name="userListingSCategory" style="display:none">
                    <?php require_once('inc/subcategories.php'); ?>
                    </div>
                    </select>
```

**Subcategories.php**

```
<?php require_once('db/dbc.php');
#GET SELECT sub-category names
$pdo3 = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
$pdo3->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare("
SELECT scatID, scatName
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE C.catID = SC.catID
;");
$sth3->execute(array());
?>

<option  disabled="disabled">Sub-Category...</option>
<?php
#Get subcats    
while($row = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{echo "<option value=". $row['scatID'] . ">" .$row['scatName']."</option>";}
unset($sth3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Diagnose the issue:

- Get the php to echo this.value to see if the contents of that are what you're expecting.
- Run the SQL query with the contents you're expecting and see if it returns the data you're expecting.

If both of those work fine each time, then something's not triggering, but the code seems sound from here.  After that, I would try putting echo statements in between your lines and see where it stops.

Comment: I have noticed, if i select an option in the first dropdown, the second dropdown clears, but then doesnt populate anything, thought?

Comment: Is it possible to just have the value of C.catID like $_POST['C.catID'] in the query `SELECT scatID, scatName
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE C.catID = SC.catID` like: `SELECT scatID, scatName
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE $_POST['C.catID'] = SC.catID` ?

Comment: It sounds like your query isn't returning any records.  Echo an extra entry into the dropdown with each iteration through the resultset, so you end up with "1", [first entry], "2", [second entry], "3", [third entry], etc. as your theoretical dropdown contents.  If all it does is put the number "1" in the dropdown, then you know it got to that bit of code, but there wasn't any data in the result.

If the amount of information you're querying is never going to be too large, you can always SELECT * FROM SubCategory GROUP BY catID, dump it into a JavaScript array, and do the filtering client-side.

Comment: If I test the query `SELECT scatID, scatName FROM Category C, SubCategory SC WHERE C.catID = SC.catID` in `phpmyadmin`, it outputs information. It seems the problem is in the ajax/jquery: `$('#SecDD').load('inc/php/subcategories.php?scatID='+this.value);` . The reason I say this is, if i view the source, all the first and second dropdown values are there on load.

Comment: If running the query yourself gets you the records you're expecting, then that leaves the content of this.value as the source.  Put it in a variable and then echo the variable to the page and see what gets printed.